# How to find a website in IIS using a custom port

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, tcp, identity

I am trying to find website with url https://example.com:8888 in iis, but iis bindings looks like this, this iis is on a vm instance hosted on azure,

[image]

when I do netstat I get this (copied picture from internet but I am getting exact same response for 8888),

[image]

Problem:

- Wildcard certificate expired on "*.example.com" we renewed it on website in iis, it shows certificate valid for 443(https) and 80(http) but it shows certificate as expired for port 8888. I am unable to find binding for this website with port 8888 so that IT team could update it's certificate.
- We stopped IIS server and website on 443 and 80 stoped serving however on port 8888 it kept showing certificate expired and didn't go down. However when we shutdown the server instance, it went down as well.

How to find this website so that we could update it's certificate ? thanks

Comment: A service can hook to HTTP API directly, without IIS, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html You can manipulate its certificate via HTTP API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check whether 8888 is listened by (PID 4)IIS by using command line:

**netstat -ano**

If the command line show that IIS is listening to 8888, then you could use this to find the binding& site with port 8888

**appcmd list site**
[image]